# how to fetch data in chunks from db in django and then delete them?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

My basic problem statement is that I want to fetch every row but in chunks only 2000 rows at one time from a table having 1 million rows. And after these chunked queries are evaluated i want to delete every row.

so just say i have

```
a = Model.objects.filter(id=1<2000)
b = Model.objects.filter(id=2000<4000)
c = Model.objects.filter(id=4000<6000)
..
..
```

now if i combine all these queryset into one queryset by some means say

`del = a + b + c +d ......`

and i do

`del.delete()`

so will it delete all the rows in less time or it will re process queries again to delete them and will take time?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Queryset's are [lazy-evaluated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy) so this will have no performance boost effect. But, ff you want to decrease memory consumption, then you can use (iterator)[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#iterator] with chunk_size parameter set:

```
for record in Model.objects.all().iterator(chunk_size=2000):
    record.delete()
```

Else, if you are actually looking for improving deletion speed, then you can try to use undocumented method [_raw_delete](https://github.com/django/django/blob/5f8495a40ab1554e81ac845484da890dd390e1d8/django/db/models/query.py#L742)

```
a = Model.objects.all()
a._raw_delete(a.db)
```

only if:

1. your models don't have cascade deleting (like foreign keys related to this model with `on_delete=CASCADE`)
2. your model have no signals to be handled

Answer (score 1):

Limit your queryset in a while loop to chunks and delete them. This helps reduce memory usage and keeps the number of SQL queries reasonable. It's tempting to use .delete() with a limited queryset but Django does not support this.

Here's an example with business logic on each object. If you don't need that, consider using values_list to capture ids.

```py
while True:
    queryset = Model.objects.all()[:2000]
    ids = []
    for obj in queryset:
       ids.append(obj.id)
       # Business logic goes here
    if ids:
       Model.objects.filter(id__in=ids).delete() # or _raw_delete
    else:
       break
```

If you really just wanted to delete everything you could do this instead. Take notice to what it's doing. Find a desired record with offset 2000. Then delete any id less than this. It assumes ids are sequential. This method uses less memory. Make sure you understand how it works before deploying. If ids are not sequential, it will delete random data. If models are constantly being created, this method could run forever. I use this method to delete old data I no longer need. I apply the date filter before the while loop, so that it won't run forever.

```py
queryset = Model.objects.all()
while True:
    try:
        delimiter = queryset.values_list("id", flat=True)[2000:2001].get()
        queryset.filter(id__lte=delimiter).delete()
    except Model.DoesNotExist:
        break
```

Other methods have problems at your scale (but are fine at the small scale). Deleting one record at a time is inefficient and probably unacceptable at the millions of rows level. _raw_delete is broadly fast, but could still be too slow. One should consider how long the database takes to respond to this. Is it really acceptable to keep this query running for several minutes? What else is happening in the database while it runs a slow delete, perhaps something else is attempting to read/update this data. That's all hard work to figure out - but chunking is easy and works.